# Order an Elasticsearch query by child

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to perform a search like this:

search(text, ID)

It should return all items that match the text, but order the results based on the score of a child with the same ID as the parent.

Suppose I have a store with the following products. The children are similar products populated by an external service that uses a machine learning algorithm to determine how similar each item is to it's parent. (not using ES similarity)

The similarity score is in parentheses after the product name.

1 - a red long sleeve shirt

- 2 - a red short sleeve shirt (90)
- 3 - a blue long sleeve shirt (90)
- 5 - a green long sleeve shirt (90)
- 4 - a blue short sleeve shirt (60)
- 6 - a green short sleeve shirt (60)

2 - a red short sleeve shirt

- 1 - a red long sleeve shirt (90)
- 4 - a blue short sleeve shirt (90)
- 6 - a green short sleeve shirt (90)
- 3 - a blue long sleeve shirt (60)
- 5 - a green long sleeve shirt (60)

3 - a blue long sleeve shirt

- 4 - a blue short sleeve shirt (90)
- 1 - a red long sleeve shirt (90)
- 5 - a green long sleeve shirt (90)
- 2 - a red short sleeve shirt (60)
- 6 - a green short sleeve shirt (60)

7 - a red ball

- 8 - a blue ball (60)
- 9 - a green ball (60)
- 1 - a red long sleeve shirt (20)
- 2 - a red short sleeve shirt (20)

8 - a blue ball

- 7 - a red ball (60)
- 9 - a green ball (60)
- 4 - a blue short sleeve shirt (20)
- 3 - a blue long sleeve shirt (20)

9 - a green ball

- 8 - a blue ball (60)
- 7 - a red ball (60)
- 6 - a green short sleeve shirt (20)
- 5 - a green long sleeve shirt (20)

10 - a red bat

- 2 - a red short sleeve shirt (20)
- 1 - a red long sleeve shirt (20)

11 - an incredible ball

- 7 - a red ball
- 8 - a blue ball
- 9 - a green ball

If I do the following search:

search("red", 1)

I should get all of the parent (top level) items that contain the text "red", but they should be ordered by the score of the child that matches the ID 1

1 - a red long sleeve shirt (100)

2 - a red short sleeve shirt (90)

7 - a red ball (20)

10 - a red bat (20)

11 - an incredible ball

I'm unsure if this is possible, I've been looking at the nested aggregate queries but am unsure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Reading the ES docs I think I need to:

a) generate a term search and pass in an ID

b) create two aggregations

- First containing the results that have children that match the ID, then perform an intrinsic sort on the results based on the score of the child that matches the ID
- Second containing any other results that don't have children that match the ID

c) perform a multivalue bucket sort where the first aggregation is returned before the second